# Distinct with only matching subdocuments

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Lets say I have some documents that looks like:

```
{
    "stuff": [
        {"thing": "A", "data": "helloworld"},
        {"thing": "A", "data": "something"},
        {"thing": "B", "data": "foobar"}
    ]
},
{
    "stuff": [
        {"thing": "A", "data": "something else"},
        {"thing": "B", "data": "foobar"}
    ]
}
```

How can I get the list of distinct `data` where `thing = A` *only*.

I know how I can `find` these subdocuments with:

```
db.col.find({"stuff.thing": "A"}, {"stuff.$":1})
```

But I can't find any info on doing a `distinct` query on the matching subdocuments only.

Comment: Try  `db.col.distinct("stuff.data", {"stuff.thing":"A"})`

Comment: @Veeram that returns _all_ `stuff.data` from all documents where _at least one subdocument_ matches `stuff.thing: "A"`. I only want `stuff.data` from the subdocuments that match.

Comment: Thats what I thought right after I posted the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation.

```
db.col.aggregate([
   {"$match":{"stuff.thing":"A"}},
   {"$unwind":"$stuff"},
   {"$match":{"stuff.thing":"A"}},
   {"$group":{"_id":"$stuff.data"}
])
```